# Deploy azure data factory v2 app

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to find any way to publish my console app (.net) written for azure data factory v2.
But could not find any solution.

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with U-SQL, I am removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details would be really appreciated but if you mean that you are using the .NET SDK to create ADF V2 objects, my understanding is that there is no such thing as publish compared to the new User Interface in the portal where you create/edit the objects first and then you click on publish.

if you use the library they get automatically uploaded to ADF V2 and you can easily test that now with the new UI.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to have a bit more info on your context. You're talking about running a [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) from an Azure Batch account? What did you try already?

When running a custom activity, you'll have to upload your executable + depedencies to an Azure storage account. Create a blob container and copy the files there. Then you'll have to configure the activity to use this storage account and the point it to the right container.

If you're asking for a deployment like a right-click -> deploy option, it doesn't exist. I've automated my deployments using PowerShell, using Set-AzureStorageBlobContent to write the files to the Storage account.